# how to return the inserted data from mysql with knexjs?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

i am learning knexjs and this is my code:

```
await knex('vendor_message').insert(data).returning(['message_id',
          'type',
          'content',
          'created_on',
          'last_update_on',
          'vendor_email']);
```

i was expecting it to return those fields from the db something like this:

```
[ 
 {
  'message_id': 'asdsd',
  'type':2,
  'content':'adddd',
  'created_on':'xxxx',
  'last_update_on':'xxxx',
  'vendor_email':'xxx@gmail.com'
 }
]
```

but it only returns the id: e.g.:

[ 687 ]

i don't want to return the arguments inserted, i want it from the db

Answer (score 4):

[`returning`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning) is not supported by **MySQL**.

> Utilized by PostgreSQL, MSSQL, and Oracle databases, the returning method specifies which column should be returned by the insert and update methods.

Just use the `insert id` to fetch the new row.